# how to swap 2 values of a two dimensional array in x86-64 assembly

Tags: assembly, matrix, x86, x86-64

I am making a program in assembly x86-64 that transposes a matrix based on the following function in c

```
void transpose_matrix_by_naive(int **matrix, const int matrixSize){

    int i, j, auxValue;

    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < matrixSize; j++){
            if (i < j){
                auxValue = matrix[i][j];
                matrix[i][j] = matrix[j][i];
                matrix[j][i] = auxValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

to create the matrix I use the following function

```
void create_matrix(int ***matrix, const int matrixSize){

    int i;

    *matrix = (int **)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(int *));
    for (i = 0; i < matrixSize; i++){
        (*matrix)[i] = (int *)malloc(matrixSize * sizeof(int));
    }    
}
```

the program in asm is

```
;extern void transpose_matrix_by_naive_in_asm(int **matrix, int matrixSize);
;                                                   RDI         RSI
section .text
    global transpose_matrix_by_naive_in_asm
transpose_matrix_by_naive_in_asm:
    mov RAX, 0
    mov RBX, 0
loop_for_i:
    loop_for_j:
        cmp RAX, RBX
        jl conditional_if
        return:
        inc RBX
        cmp RBX, RSI
        jne loop_for_j
    inc RAX
    cmp RAX, RSI
    jne loop_for_i
conditional_if:
    ;here I have to make a swap
    jmp return
```

and my question is ¿how to exchange the values of matrix [i] [j] and matrix [j] [i]?. It is worth mentioning that I am working with square matrices only.

Comment: Break it down.  Seeing as you now have `i` and `j` in registers `RAX, RBX` respectively, how would you load `matrix[i]` into a register?  Then how would you load `matrix[i][j]`?  Repeat for `matrix[j][i]`, loading into a different register.  Then store them back reversed.

Comment: Also watch out for the calling conventions.  You didn't specify your OS, but you need to find out which registers are call-preserved in your ABI, and make sure to save and restore those registers.  In particular RBX is call-preserved under both SysV (Linux) and Microsoft conventions.

Comment: You also need to reinitialize RBX inside the outer loop, not just once at the top.  Note there is an easy optimization possible here, that will cut the number of iterations in half and avoid the need for the `cmp RAX, RBX`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In x86 assembler two values in memory are swapped simply by

```
 mov eax, [rdi]
 mov ebx, [rsi]
 mov [rdi], ebx
 mov [rsi], eax
```

where `rdi`, `rsi` are the memory addresses of two 32-bit integers.
The address calculation should be typically speeded up by calculating *strides* or offsets which to skip to get the Nth element right or down.

The whole matrix transpose in assembler is likely best generated by a compiler.
OTOH a compiler is likely not able to use SIMD instructions as when breaking the operations to block of 4x4 submatrices:

```
for (y = 0; y < size/4; y++) {
    for (x = 0; x < y; x++) {
        if (y == x) {
            transposeSubBlock(matrix, y);
        } else if (y < x) {
            transposeSubBlock(matrix, y, x);
        }
    }
}
```

Now transposing a single 4x4 block on the matrix diagonal happens by loading 4 SIMD registers (from adjacent rows and adjacent columns), transposing the registers, and writing back.

```
__m128i a[4];
a[0] = _mm_loadu_si128(row + 0 * stride);
a[1] = _mm_loadu_si128(row + 1 * stride);
a[2] = _mm_loadu_si128(row + 2 * stride);
a[3] = _mm_loadu_si128(row + 3 *stride);
transpose(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
_mm_storeu_si128(row + 0 * stride, a[0]);
_mm_storeu_si128(row + 1 * stride, a[1]);
_mm_storeu_si128(row + 2 * stride, a[2]);
_mm_storeu_si128(row + 3 * stride, a[3]);
```

The other blocks are handled by loading two 4x4 blocks, transposes both blocks in registers, and writing to the opposite target.

```
__m128i a[4], b[4];
load4vectors(a, src0, stride);
load4vectors(b, src1, stride);
transpose(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
transpose(b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);
store4vectors(src0, b[0],b[1],b[2],b[3]);
store4vectors(src1, a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

One possible way to transpose a matrix of int[4][4] is to cast each element to `__m128` apply `MM_TRANSPOSE_PS(a,b,c,d);` macro and cast each element back to `__m128i`.

The remaining task is to handle the excess elements, that are not multiples of 4.